# getting an error while connecting mongodb with replicaset-Bitnami

Tags: mongodb, azure, bitnami

I have deployed bitnami MongoDB with replicaset on Azure and I haven't changed anything but when I try to connect MongoDB using connection string then I'm getting an error like `

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [xyz.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketReadTimeoutException): Timeout while receiving message
|____/ I/O error: Read timed out

Details:
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=xyz.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out}}]
```

I have running bitnami mongodb with replicaset on azure which was created one month back that time i haven't faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the address may have changed. I advise you to confirm that xyz.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com still points to the same IP address you want to connect. Also check that there are no firewall rules blocking the traffic.

Comment: Not sure how IP address changing would impact the OP, since they're using a dns name.